# SocketException:Connection Failed(OS Error: Too many open files, errno = 24)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of dio requests, and get the result by Future.wait. Maybe the number of dio requests has exceeded the maximum that dart supports, so the app throw an error -SocketException:Connection Failed(OS Error: Too many open files, errno = 24). After i limit the length of dio requests in Future.wait, it works well. So i would like to know what is maximum limit of the list in Future.wait for Dart language

```dart
resultList.addAll(await Future.wait(
              _list.map((e) => e.requestInterface()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not try limit the amount of connections by limiting the amount of futures you are spawning and waiting on. Instead, you it is better to tell `Dio` (or more precise, the `HttpClient` instance inside `Dio`) the maximum amount of connections you want to the same host.

So first, make sure you are reusing the same instance of `Dio` at least for all requests to the same host. We can then use this property to tell `HttpClient` how many simultaneous requests it should try to handle to the same host. If the amount of requests are more than the limit, it will automatically handle this as a queue.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-io/HttpClient/maxConnectionsPerHost.html

The default of this property are `null` which disables any maximum which is a problem in cases like your where you are doing a lot of requests. But also, performance would often there are a limit where it no longer gives better performance trying to do more requests simultaneous.

You need to play with the property to find where a good value are for you. But I would guess it is between 5 and 15 depending on the application of course.

To provide this property to `Dio` we can do the following:

```dart
  final dio = Dio();
  dio.httpClientAdapter = DefaultHttpClientAdapter()
    ..onHttpClientCreate =
        (httpClient) => httpClient..maxConnectionsPerHost = 20;
```

(And to answer the actual question, the error message comes from the operating system where your application are running on. It is hard to say what the actual limit are since it is possible to set specific limitation on the specific applications to ensure a single application are not making too much noise on the system.).